# Phaser assets loading issue from JSON file

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, phaser-framework

I have the following code for a Phaser game. It's just used to get a visual idea for a level by loading information from a JSON file using AJAX.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>hello phaser!</title>
        <script src="phaser.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">



        var game = new Phaser.Game(1024, 768, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create,renderer:renderer});
        var background;

        function preload () 
        {

                game.load.image('bg','bg.png');
                game.load.image('mothership', 'bird.png');
                game.load.image('turret','turret.png');





        }

        function create () 
        {
            //game.add.sprite(31,725,"mothership");
            //game.add.sprite(100,100,"turret");
            //background=game.add.sprite(0,0,"bg");
            //background.scale.setTo(5,7);


        }

        function renderer()
        {

        }
        $.ajax({
                        url: "TestFile5.json",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType:"application/json",
                        success: function(response) {
                            //here you can use the response
                                //response can be passed to what ever js file you need.


                                game.add.sprite(response.mothership.posx, response.mothership.posy, "mothership");

                                game.add.sprite(response.Turret0.posx, response.Turret0.posy, "turret");
                                game.add.sprite(response.Turret1.posx, response.Turret1.posy, "turret");
                                game.add.sprite(response.Turret2.posx, response.Turret2.posy, "turret");

                        },
                        error: function(response1){
                                alert('response error')
                        }
                    });






    </script>
</Body>
</html>
```

I have loaded this onto my online server along with the JSON file and images but it doesn't seem to load the images using the `game.add.sprite()` function in the AJAX callback. I get the screen with placeholder images. The positions are correct but the image isn't loaded. What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Dev Tools panel in your browser (F12 in IE, ctrl+shift+j in Chrome) and check the Network panel to be 100% sure that the assets did actually load. If the images failed to load you should also see an entry in the console as well, as Phaser will throw a warning there.

Also it's worth mentioning that Phaser can load json files. So you could start your game with a Boot state that loads the json with all the position data in it, parse it and have it ready for your Game state which can use the positioning / texture values inside of it. Then you won't have any potential scope issues (which you may well end up with here).

Comment: could you give an example of the the Phaser loading an image stored in say a .json file located in the assets folder

Comment: also i checked the dev tools and it throws no warnings or errors.so the code i gave is correct

Comment: Inside your 'success' function check to make sure the images have actually loaded and are in the cache: game.cache.checkImageKey('turret'). If false then a race condition has probably occurred (the ajax completed before the preload did). If true I still suspect a scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this on another forum as came across this post because I was experiencing the same problem. http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/1936-import-files-and-data-json-parser/.

Basically, I had to use Phaser's `game.load.text('assetList','path/to/file.json')` method and then `JSON.parse(game.cache.getText('assetList'));` and all started to work very well.